# Map Reduce - using a local variable in a Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I've implemented a simple Map reduce application for detecting a longest word. The job executes successfully.
But now I wonder if it was correct to use a local variable in the reducer to keep Max length? Since there may be multiple reducers in a distributed environment and they do not share the value of that variable.

Is it a correct assumption?

How will the output be affected in a distributed environment when there are independent reducers?
I'm using a custom comparator so the words are sorted by length first and than by value. The output on each MR stage looks like this:

```
Mapper Output:
ByeByeBye   9
HelloHelloHe222 15
HelloHelloHe222 15
HelloHelloHe333 15
HelloHelloHe333 15
HelloHelloHellw99999 20

Combiner Output:
ByeByeBye   9
HelloHelloHe222 15
HelloHelloHe333 15
HelloHelloHellw99999    20

ComparatorOutput:
HelloHelloHellw99999    20
HelloHelloHe222 15
HelloHelloHe333 15
ByeByeBye   9

Reducer Output:
HelloHelloHellw99999    20
```

**The Reducer class:**

```
public class WordsReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private IntWritable length = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        length = values.iterator().next();
        if (length.get() >= maxLength){
            maxLength = length.get();
            context.write(key, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see the need for the Comparator, because finding the greatest max shouldn't require a sorted dataset.

Finding the maximum of any dataset is a map-only operation. Finding the overall maximum of multiple map tasks requires reducing those individual tasks, and that can only be done by one reducer where it has all the data available to compare.

Your reducer code only outputs the max *per reducer*. And your key is the text, but there are multiple texts, so there's no chance it sees the overall maximum. The reason you got one output is because the combiner had already collected the unique strings into one item and the items were sorted in descending order.

You need that logic that only outputs the max length of a string on the mapper, probably using a TreeMap to store intermediate lengths while iterating over the tokens, not writing the current maximum of the iteration. And using a field is fine, but it's not shared over all tasks. You'd use Counter objects for that, and those are stored in the Context object.

If you wanted the overall max without a Combiner with your current code, you would run it twice, given the input of the first run's output. Imagine this scenario, Reducer 1 finishes with a max length of 15, Reducer 2 finishes with a max length of 20. So, then you've written two outputs, not just the overall maximum.

As mentioned, each map task needs to write its respective maximum string. Then, you actually can use a NullWritable as a key, outputting `null, "length,word"`. In the Reducer, you then take all the values, extract the length, find the greatest one, and print it